# json_serializable package problematic conversion to double in flutter

Tags: flutter, json-serializable

I have a following class:

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'account_filter.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class AccountFilter {
  double latitude = 0;
  double longitude = 0;
  String city = "";
  String country = "";
  int minAge = 18;
  int maxAge = 99;
  int gender = 1;

  AccountFilter(
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.city,
    this.country,
    this.minAge,
    this.maxAge,
    this.gender,
  );

  factory AccountFilter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AccountFilterFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AccountFilterToJson(this);
}
```

After `dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` generated file looks like this:

```dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'account_filter.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

AccountFilter _$AccountFilterFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
    AccountFilter(
      (json['latitude'] as num).toDouble(), // <-- IMPORTANT!!!
      (json['longitude'] as num).toDouble(), // <-- IMPORTANT!!!
      json['city'] as String,
      json['country'] as String,
      json['minAge'] as int,
      json['maxAge'] as int,
      json['gender'] as int,
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$AccountFilterToJson(AccountFilter instance) =>
    <String, dynamic>{
      //... some code
    };
```

During deserialization I receive the following error
`type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num' in type cast`

Of course, the problem lies in the line

```dart
json['latitude'] as num).toDouble(),
```

How can I solve this problem elegantly? In my original solution I set `longitude` and `latitude` to be strings, renamed them to `longitudeString` and `latitudeString` and created two getters:

```dart
  double get latitude => double.parse(latitudeString);
  double get longitude => double.parse(longitudeString);
```

but I am looking for more convenient solution.

Comment: No. That is the code generated by standard `json_serializable` package used for json serialization and deserialization.  I know what I would do if I do it manually, but I have many models, so this package is the only reasonable solution.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see that. This is just my error while copy/paste my code with solution where I used Strings instead of doubles. Thanks for pointing out. I've changed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it.

First, I defined public method:

```dart
double toDouble(String number) {
  return double.parse(number);
}
```

I've made the following changes to class `AccountFilter`:

```dart
@JsonSerializable()
class AccountFilter {
  @JsonKey(fromJson: toDouble)
  double latitude;
  @JsonKey(fromJson: toDouble)
  double longitude;
  String city = "";
  String country = "";
  int minAge = 18;
  int maxAge = 99;
  int gender = 1;

AccountFilter(
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
    this.city,
    this.country,
    this.minAge,
    this.maxAge,
    this.gender,
  );

  factory AccountFilter.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AccountFilterFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AccountFilterToJson(this);
}
```

Basically, I set the method `toDouble` as a `fromJson` parameter in `@JsonKey` annotation used for correctly parsing the data.

Comment: Ah, if your JSON is storing floating-point numbers as strings (i.e., `latitude: "12.34"` instead of `latitude: 12.34`), then yeah, I think this is the way to go.  You should be able to do `@JsonKey(fromJson: double.parse)` directly without needing to create a `toDouble` function though.

Comment: I will try that. Sounds reasonable. Thanks!